# Border-bottom from left to right

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to transition border-bottom from left to right. I'm not quite sure how to go on doing it, and tried different things but haven't really come any close to figuring it out.

As far as now I got

```
.menu-text {
font-size: 1em;
height: 120px;
margin-top: -10px;
background: #334960;
padding-right: 35px;
color: #FFF;
text-decoration: none;  
line-height: 125px;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
transition: all ease-in-out .2s;
border-bottom: 10px solid #334960;
}

.menu-text:hover {
border-bottom: 10px solid #FFF;
}
```

I appreciate any help I get, thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean transition it from left to right?

Comment: @Banana Like a sliding effect, where the border starts from left then transition over to the right instead of bottom to top

Comment: from your code i see you only change the color on hover, do you want the border to color gradiently from left to right until or something of the sort?

Comment: @Banana No, I want the border to gradiently appear, like a transition from 2px to 100px.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not animate border in this manner. You have to use pseudo element `after`. Animate the width of this element from left to right!

```
.menu-text {
    font-size: 1em;
    height: 120px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    background: #334960;
    padding-right: 35px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;  
    line-height: 125px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.menu-text:after {
    transition: all ease-in-out .2s;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 0;
}
.menu-text:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: @AndreasEilertsenLybo Which browser you are using ? And your body background color must be different from white.
Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w6jfjvdg/2/